# How to Correctly Pour a Hefeweizen

Tags: hefeweizen

I order everything from Northern Brewer and in my experience they have always suggested secondary fermentation, except for a hefeweizen that I have ready to drink.

I assumed this was because hefeweizens were supposed to be cloudy and secondary fermentation tends to reduce cloudiness.

Naturally my bottles have a much larger layer of yeast in them then I have seen from my other beers.

I just poured two bottles into two glasses. The first bottle I poured every last drop. The second bottle I poured until I noticed the yeast about to flow out.

Which is the proper way to pour a hefeweizen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions for Paulaner Hefe-Weizen specify

1. Rinse your glass with cold water
2. Hold your glass in an incline and pour carefully
3. Leave some beer in the bottle and gently shake it to mix the yeast at the bottom with the remaining beer
4. Pour the mixed beer and yeast into the glass and enjoy your Paulaner Hefe-Weizen

Comment: Someone I know who brews only hefes rolls his bottles on the table or counter top to put all the yeast into suspension. Then pours out the cloudiest but very taste hefe. Yeast in a hefe is a must.

Comment: Nice. Sounds like a great idea.